# How to decompose the tables for optimal querying

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, database-table

Suppose I have three tables Actor, Movie, Producer with following attributes

**Actor(Id,ActorName,Bio)**

**Producer(Id,ProducerName,Bio)**

**Movie(Id,Name,Description,ActorName,ProducerName)**

There can be many actors in a movie and actor can act many movies, same goes with producer.
How to effectively decompose/create new tables to store data. I tried creating a new table with following schema

**ActorMovie(Id, MovieId, ActorId)**

but failed as there can be multiple actors in a movie.

Comment: You said your `ActorMovie` table failed, but what do you mean by that? It's the right solution, which becomes more apparent if you lose the implementation-detail-based table name `ActorMovie` and instead call it `Cast`, because the set of actors in a movie is called the cast! :) The `id` column on this table is superfluous. The primary key is just the combination of `MovieId` and `ActorId`, *unless* you want to be able to support movies where one actor plays multiple roles, in which case you would need to add a `role` column to the table, and it would then include the role in the key.

Comment: @nihar Please check my answer and let me know if it does not serve your purpose. Best wishes.

Comment: Sorry for that naming convention, english is not my first language, but if I create that table, we can have multiple actors in a single movie so there data might become redundant right? is it possible to eliminate this redundancy? Suppose I send a post call to db to add movie, how i need to make my model look like?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple rows that have the same value for `MovieId` in the `Cast` table, but that's OK. If I read between the lines here, I think you've got yourself into the belief that if a column in a table has the same value on different rows, then that's a normal form violation, and I can sort of see why people might think this. But that's not right, and the example you are using here demonstrates why that is. Each row in the Cast table is a unique combination of movie and actor, even though there can be multiple rows in the table with same movie. That's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have a solution for you. As I understand from your description, your table should be look like below.
**Actor(Id,ActorName,Bio);** 
**Producer(Id,ProducerName,Bio);**
**Movie(Id,Name,Description);**
**ActorMovie(Id, MovieId, ActorId);**
**ProducerMovie(Id,MovieId, ProducerId);**

And Relationship Diagram should be look like this.
[image]

**Note: Symbols of relationship might not be correct but connections should look like above.**

Comment: In the ActorMovie table, I can have movie with multiple actors right, so how to handle that?

Comment: @nihar Can you explain with some sample data or some images?

Comment: Yes @nihar . I can store different actor of different movies in actor movie table.

Comment: Suppose there is a movie Avenge, it has actors rob,mike,john so the table must look like this right   (1 34  2) (2 34 21) (3 34 98) So how can I frame a model for rest api call?

Comment: @nihar yes. but mentioned about redundant information. Which one you refer as redundant information.

Comment: I am unable to frame a model based on the above decomposition, like if I add data in movie table, I need to insert the same into ActorMovie and ProducerMovie right? How can i frame a model and insert in both of those while inserting into movie table

Comment: @nihar your movie should have List of Producers and List of Actors. So, First insert The movie information the insert ActorMovie (List of Actors) then ProducerMovie (List of Producers).